# How to select rows based on value of column next to them

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns:

```
14:40   1   4
14:40   1   0
14:40   1   4
14:45   1   3
14:45   1   2
14:45   1   1
14:45   1   1
14:45   1   2
```

I need to select, cut and copy cells from column 2 and 3 based on values from 1. I need to find the row where 14:40 changes to 45 and move the two columns (to the right), repeat the process with 45 until the last row.

Comment: cut AND copy? do you mean paste? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you're asking for.

In the second row, D2, type the function `=IF($A2<>$A1,B2,"")`. Copy that to the right (I use fill right), into E2. Then copy D2 and E2 to the last row and fill down.

(What the function does is sees if A2 is equal to A1. The dollar sign keeps the comparison between A2 and A1 for other columns, such as E. It then prints B2 if they are not equal, or a blank if they are equal.)

Every time the time changes in column A, you'll get the numbers in B and C copied over to D and E.

You can alternatively do a conditional format to make them bold.

Comment: To Sam - you are correct. I need to copy and paste to the right.

Comment: To rajah9 - it was helpful. I have a macro that moves cells from B and C to the right. So far my selection has to be manual. So my macro lads on the first row in B, I select B and C going down until A changes and then start macro which cuts and moves B and C. Having something placed in the rows in which A changes is helpful, but it is difficult for me to use it in a macro, as it seems to be invisible to end-down arrow.  Thanks anyway.